# How to get a letter of invitation to travel to Canada?

Tags: visas, canada, invitation-letters

I want to visit Canada with my family. I have  no relatives or anyone known in Canada. Now how can i  have a letter of invitation to visit Canada?

Comment: Why do you want a letter of invitation? You do not need such a letter. It is not required to obtain a visa.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a letter of invitation to visit Canada. The [Canadian Government's website](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada.html) will tell you if you need a visa and, if so, what you need to do to apply for one.